# The guidelines for choosing different MCMC algorithms

Tags: markov-chain-montecarlo, metropolis-hastings, gibbs, hamiltonian-monte-carlo, mcmc-acceptance-rate

MCMC has several types of algorithms: Metropolis-Hastings, Gibbs, Adaptive MH, Hamiltonian Monte Carlo. What are their respective pro/cons, and how to choose them in the Bayesian analysis?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MCMC with Metropolis-Hastings algorithm: Choosing proposal](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/100121/mcmc-with-metropolis-hastings-algorithm-choosing-proposal)

Comment: It depends on your problem, your model, etc. I suggest that you add more material to the question: about the problem that you are trying to solve, and about how you understand the algorithms that you listed (perhaps the one that you need is not even mentioned.)